# I am getting some errors in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I took a course about Flutter from udemy. I've come to the Firebase part. However, I am getting errors in this part. I am getting an error even though I type exactly the same. I think I got error like this because there are updates in Flutter language. I'm sorry my English is bad. Thank you in advance for helping me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E14Sx.png)

main.dart

```
import 'dart:html';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:fire_base1/user.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Future<List<User>> getData() async {
    final res = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").get();

    List<User> myresult = <User>[];
    for (int i = 0; i < res.docs.length; i++) {
      User user = new User(
          name: res.docs[i]["name"],
          last_name: res.docs[i]["last_name"],
          email: res.docs[i]["email"]);
      myresult.add(user);
    }
    return myresult;
  }

  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("FireBase"),
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder(
          future: Firebase.initializeApp(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text("Veritabanına bağlanırken bir hata meydana geldi");
            }
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              return FutureBuilder(
                future: getData(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    );
                  } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                    return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return ListTile(
                          title: Text(snapshot.data[index].name +
                              " " +
                              snapshot.data[index].last_name),
                          subtitle: Text(snapshot.data[index].email),
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  } else {
                    return SizedBox();
                  }
                },
              );
            }
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          },
        ));
  }
}
```

user.dart

```
class User {
  String name;
  String last_name;
  String email;

  User({required this.name, required this.last_name, required this.email});

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data["name"] = name;
    data["last_name"] = last_name;
    data["email"] = email;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please always copy/paste the error your IDE or your runtime shows in here. Screenshots won't help much.

Anyways, by looking at your image it seems like that `data` is a nullable variable, and therefore accessing it throws a compile-time error because of [sound null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety).

You have two options:

1. Riskier and inelegant hasty option: just add a bang operator `!` to perform a null check, in which you're telling Dart that you're sure that `data` isn't null
2. Robust, elegant, well-thought option: learn and use the null-aware operators such as `?.`, `??` and `??=`.

For example in the following snippet (by looking at your code):

```
itemCount: snapshot.data.length
```

I'd do something like:

```
itemCount: snapshot.data?.length ?? 0
```

Which solution might not be correct - it depends on your business logic, i.e. what you want to do.

The inelegant option would be something like

```
if (data != null)
    itemCount: snapshot.data!.length
```

Which can lead to unexpected runtime errors in the long run.

Comment: When you leave class, do what you say.  I will inform the result in more detail.  Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Upvote my answer if it helped :-) Thank you.